# При выборе датчика менять диаграмму, картинку и показатели

Tags: excel, vba

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доабрый день как сделать такое на VBA? При выборе датчика меняется диаграмма, картинка и показатели

Comment: Ну просто управляете сериями диаграммы - добавляете, убираете... или управляете данными в диапазоне источника данных, скажем, меняете базу.

Comment: Два пути: 1) показать не картинку, а пример с наработками и проблемой; 2) заказать работу на фриланс-сервисе

Comment: Есть ещё и третий путь - на [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%B2+excel) в строке поиска вбить "создание дашборда в excel" и через час стать профи ("через час" - потому что хорошие ролики-уроки приблизительно столько и длятся, более короткие не очень понятны для новичков)